# How to implement image distortion effects in Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing, distortion

I want to implement distortion effects on image in Android. I did the same in iOS(iPhone and iPad) by using GPUImage framework. Is there any framework or library available in Android to do the same. 
 I want to implement following distortion effects in Android.

pinch distortion

swirl distortion

bulge distortion

stretch distortion

Please provide any solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have done it successfully , will you please help me out with any link or something, how you did this?

Comment: Kindly let me know if anyone found any demo on this.

Comment: @Sanchit Paurush, have you found any solution? I am looking for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very basic example in your SDK folder into the APIDemos project. See `SDK_DIR/samples/android-*/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/BitmapMesh.java`.

Also answers for [Resources for image distortion algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225548/resources-for-image-distortion-algorithms) may help.

Comment: Is there any Demo link? My app have similar feature like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.warp