# Image Morphing Effect in Android

Tags: android, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement image distortion effects in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137115/how-to-implement-image-distortion-effects-in-android)

Just wondering how to work with Image Processing(Morphing), I want to have ability of morphing effect to an Image

something similar like this apps given below

[1. Face Effect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.warp&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hcHBzcG90LnN3aXNzY29kZW1vbmtleXMud2FycCJd)

[2. Photo Warp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.tonuzaba.android&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImh1LnRvbnV6YWJhLmFuZHJvaWQiXQ..)..

I tried [Bitmap Mesh code](http://code.google.com/p/android-examples/source/browse/trunk/BitmapMesh/src/com/android/bitmapmesh/BitmapMesh.java?r=5), but its not what I want.

Any **idea/hint/link** appreciable.