# Android - How to give your layout a 3D style?

Tags: android, android-layout

I was surfing the web to find a new style for the android layout and I find a pretty interesting one. Here is the Image.

[image]

I know more than basics about layout, but what I wanna is how can I give a 3d style look like in the above image? Especially that `#7881 Code Box`.

Here is Something that I have tried.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:bottom="-25dp"
        android:top="-25dp"
        android:left="25dp"
        android:right="25dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="20">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size
                    android:width="50dp"
                    android:height="100dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#E30B3E"/>
            </shape>

        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**The output is this**

[image]

Overall it gives the `textview` a 3d look but I want something like that in the image.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with xml drawables. It's probably possible at runtime (see link), but that's inefficient. I would just create the image/vector in some image editing software. I'm guessing that's what they did in your screenshot too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225548/resources-for-image-distortion-algorithms

Comment: This could be interesting too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375130/skewing-a-text-view-in-android/11381021

Comment: @einUsername is right. Since xml drawables can only produce basic shapes and a trapez with round corners is not a basic shape, it is not possible with this technique. See my answer for a free tool to easily create complex svg and import them using AS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its pretty much simple just use  `android:rotationX` property on the `CardView`
like this

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        ...
        android:rotationX="20"
        ...
```

[image: android:rotationX="20"][image: android:rotationX="10"]

Answer (score 0):

That's easy as long as the box should not be animated in its shape.

1. Go to https://www.figma.com/ and start a new project (it's free)
2. Export any shape you create there as svg
3. Import this svg into Android Studio using the Resource Manager
4. add your new drawable as background of the box.

Additional input, so your 50 points aren't wasted ;) :

- You find several Android Presets for figma. Like UI Elements  or buttons. For example [here](https://www.figma.com/resources/assets/material-design-ui-kit/). For more just google for "Figma Android UI kit"
- You can edit the generated SVG to your likes. Since it is only a text file, you can customize its colors (also using `backgroundTint` in xml), etc.

Comment: And to add .. you need to create drawables for different screen sizes

Comment: @AgentP not when using svgs. they have a `dp` value in the xml which enables Android to scale them accordingly. To make use of that, the minimum SDK needs to be 21 as far as I remember (Lollipop)

Comment: Yeah, you were right ... I got confused with the definition of dp itself for a minute

Comment: You don't have to create multiple SVG as per device size. Simple use `sdp` instead of `dp` and it will automatically adjust the size as per the device.  https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: Dude, this library is centuries old. If you use SVGs, the one single xml file is all you need. no libraries, no multiple files, no scaling.